# Slurm - Group ID not found

Tags: slurm

As I'm getting resources granted (salloc) when I try to run any command using srun, I'm getting the error:

```
    group ID not found
```

Do you know what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The group whose `ID` is mentioned does not exist on the compute/execute node even though is might exist on the submission/frontend node.

Make sure the group is properly sync across all nodes (i.e. exist in all /etc/group files or in the NIS or the LDAP directory)